# Wildcard in jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to retrieve all elements which start with a specific ID. After a short search, the solution appeared to be:

```
$('*[id^="foo_"]')
```

to select all elements with an ID starting with `foo_`. Although this selector syntax is very logical, I was just wondering whether it is possible to do this in a more 'shorthand' way, like:

```
$('#foo_*');
```

This did not work, however. Is there support for wildcarting like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no native way to do this.

However, [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) is a filter that allows regular expressions to be used for selectors. It should suit you just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the link, looks very useful!

Answer (score 3):

The selector syntax is almost identical to CSS, in which * means all selectors, rather than a wildcard. There's no need to specify the * in this case: `[id^="foo_"]` will act in the same way but with slightly less specificity.

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't. `*` is a [universal selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#universal-selector) meaning "Any element", not a generic wild card. `[id^="foo_"]` and `*[id^="foo_"]` are identical (except for [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) considerations).